# construction of normed linear spaces from inner product spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

How do i construct a normed linear space from a inner product space and verify that what i have suggested is true, that is, a test of verification. Moreover, does the norm have to satisfy the parallelogram law?

Answer (score 2):

Start with the inner product defined on the space then check the requirements for a [normed vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space). The parallelogram law should hold in your norm space.